# How to flatten value tuple of a key-value tuple?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections

I have an RDD like `[(Int, Iterable[Int])]` (key-value format). I want to flatten the value part.

I have tried:

```
rdd.productIterator.foreach(x =>  x._2.productIterator.foreach(print))
```

However, I get the following error:

> error: value _2 is not a member of Any
>            rdd.productIterator.foreach(x => x._2.productIterator.foreach(print))

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want `flatMapValues`:

```
val rdd: RDD[(Int, Iterable[Int])] = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, Seq(1, 2, 3))))
rdd.flatMapValues(idenitity)
```

Answer (score 0):

flattening the value part should be solved by doing

```
rdd.flatMap(x => x._2.map(y => y)).foreach(println)
```

If you are looking to `flatten` *key* with each of the *iterable value* then following should solve your issue

```
rdd.flatMap(x => x._2.map(y => (x._1, y))).foreach(println)
```